# What is the difference between render and return in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to **JavaScript**. I see lot of places `return` and `render` being used just want to know what's the difference between them.

Comment: Your question is mostly about the JavaScript language. Please learn the language constructs.

Answer (score 47):

`render` method is required when you are writing a React component using as a class method

According to the docs:

> The `render()` method is required.
>
> When called, it should examine `this.props` and `this.state` and
>   return one of the following types:
>
> **React elements.** Typically created via JSX. An element can either be a representation of a native DOM component `(<div />)`, or a
>   user-defined composite component `(<MyComponent />)`.
>
> **String and numbers.** These are rendered as text nodes in the DOM.
>
> **Portals.** Created with `ReactDOM.createPortal`. null. Renders nothing.
>
> **Booleans.** Render nothing. (Mostly exists to support return test &&  pattern, where test is boolean.)

Essentially render is kind of a lifecycle method which is invoked whenever the component needs to update.

As for the `return` statement, its used to return the `data/response/JSX elements` depending on where it is used. If used in render method you need to return one of the above specified types(React elements, Strings and numbers, Portals or Booleans).

`return` from other function can either return the value evaluated from the function or `return` the React elements to be rendered in the `render` method

`Functional components` don't define a `render` method, instead they return the React elements using an `explicit return statement` or an `implicit return`

**Eg: explicit return**

```
const Welcome = (props) => {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
```

**Eg: Implicit return**

```
const Welcome = (props) => (
     <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
)
```

Comment: Could you have both a render and return on the same react.js file? Or is it one or the other?

Comment: @AdanVivero welcome to SO. Please read the answer thorough before commenting: `If used in render method you need to return one of the above specified types(React elements, Strings and numbers, Portals or Booleans).`

Answer (score 35):

In React prior to the newest version (v16), most React Components were class based. In a class based component, you call the `render()` method and then `return` the required JSX (html like javascript mix). With the update of React 16+, there is an increased use of functional components which do not have a `render()` method, instead returning the JSX directly. For example the syntax of a functional component may be like this:

```
const NewComponent = (props) => {
   return (
           <div>
               <h1>Title</h1>
           </div>
    )
}
```

alternatively, you can implicitly return JSX in a functional component without the return statement like this:

```
const NewComponent = (props) => (
   <div>
       <h1>Title</h1>
   </div>
)
```

Both of these will show the same as a class based component like this:

```
class NewComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <h1>Title</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

You can read more at https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Thanks - this seems to be the most comprehensive, up to date explanation here at the moment.

Comment: Is it more wiser than to just use the render rather than the return? It doesn't seem that the return really have much purpose rather than just for basic displaying purposes.

Comment: As far as I have seen, render() let's say: generate the blue prints but the return will contain the required data to return as on the following example of @TylerDaniel below.

Answer (score 7):

Render is what is actually being called in the component, return is what is "rendered".  You can log, set variables, conditional rendering etc in the render, but return is what is actually output

```
render() {
console.log("Test")
const test = "test"
  return(
    <h1>Hi</h1>
  )
}
```

Comment: i like this answer since it also describes the limitations of return , i.e. in return everything js must be in curly braces

Comment: @A.R.B No, return has no limitations. You always have to separate Code from html.

Answer (score 4):

return and render are different. render is a method of react. return is just pure javascript for returning output. nothing complicated.

Answer (score 2):

In react, render is a method that tell react what to display. return in a method or function is the output of the method or function.

Answer (score 1):

render() is like the warm-up and planning phrase before the ball game starts.  Everyone knows what's gonna happen and then return is the player on the field that actually does what the render () says should happen.

Answer (score 1):

Render is a method that tell react what to display.

Return is a method / give output of function

Comment: Could you provide some examples?

Answer (score 1):

"The **render** method **returns** a description of what the DOM should look like, and then React efficiently updates the real DOM to match."

For the best example to know the difference, do check out this link: https://quickleft.com/blog/understanding-the-difference-between-react-elements-and-components/

Answer (score -1):

**Render** is that what exactly you want to trigger multiple times.

**Return** is that which u want to Display.

**For example.**

**render**(){

let cardDisplay=some random text which u want to trigger multiple times.
(Example, Displaying the names of employees in a company)}

**return**

(
{cardDisplay}
)

**Explanation**: You want to Display the list of employees in a company.so return the variable which you want to trigger(repeat)multiple times. Inside Render write what your logic for what to repeat.

Comment: give some proper example

Comment: Also, add references to the documentation to co-relate what you are saying.

Comment: It was a just a simple example. no references are available.

Comment: Could you use the render and return on the same file you are working on?