# setState not working with import class component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have made a Class Component Token & import in App.js
In App.js, there is api having headers with Authorisation Key (i.e. Token)

I have tried this code so far

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Token from './Token';

    class App extends Component {

      constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = { sliders: '', auth_key: ''};
      }

      componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({
          auth_key: <Token />
        });
      }

      componentDidMount = () => {
        //POST json
        var dataToSend = { userid: '223' };

        //POST request
        fetch('API/PATH', {
          method: 'POST', //Request Type
          body: dataToSend, //post body
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': this.state.auth_key
          },
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
          this.setState({ sliders: responseJson });
          alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
      }

      render(){
        return this.state.sliders;
      }

    }

    export default App;
```

this.state.auth_key in Authorisation not working. Please help to sort out this.

Token Component Class from which Token get passes to each component

```
import {Component} from "react";

export default class Token extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {tokenid: ''};
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        let formBody = { usertoken: '223' };

        fetch('API/PATH', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formBody,
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
            this.setState({
                'tokenid' : responseJson.authtoken
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
            this.setState({
                'tokenid' : ''
            })
        });
    }

    render(){
        return this.state.tokenid;
    }
}
```

Comment: why does the token has to be a component?

Comment: because i have to use this token in overall project to hit Rest Api

Comment: Can you share the code of `Token`?. If it's simply a string, you don't have to make it a component, just export the string, it can still be used by the whole project. By the way, you should make sure this key is not private.

Comment: You can define a shared function to do that instead, it will work as well.
If you want help setting that up, just show `<Token />` component content so we may refactor it into a simple Function that returns the token.

Comment: edited my question, please check

Comment: create a `service` to get `tokenid` in `App.js` I don't see point in creating Component for this purpose and I would suggest avoid using `componentWillMount` which will be going to deprecate in upcoming verison of `react` due to `asynchronous rendering` you can use `UNSAFE_componentWillMount` instead for more explanation please see this link https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle

Comment: @AviatorX, can you please share any link related to create service, as i am newbee, Thanks in Advance

Comment: How about storing tokenid in a global state?  Redux/localstorage ?

Comment: But why this is not working, <Token /> works perfect in render() but not in componentWillMount

Comment: create a utility function which will fetch `token.id` on component lifecycle of `App`. for utility function you can use code from `componentDidMount` of `<Token/>`.  regarding why <Token /> is not working? can you please explain what is current behavior?

Comment: when i have code this
`console.log('tokenid '+ JSON.stringify(<Token />) );` in componentWillMount, it results me
`tokenid {"key":null,"ref":null,"props":{},"_owner":null,"_store":{}}`

Comment: I think this is not working because what you returning is not React element. so when `render()` method is called basically react use `reconciliation` to check what changes to be done in DOM and return a `javascript object` which is used to update DOM, that's the reason you are getting object. generaaly compoennt is something which is used to decide what should be shown on screen. you can see more explanation in answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078679/what-is-the-difference-between-render-and-return-in-reactjs